# drawImage() doesn't work properly javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, drawimage

I am creating a game for school using Javascript and libraries. Now my problem is, that my drawImage doesn't work for my background image.

```
//Javascript:
$(document).ready(function() { 
// To do: code schrijven 
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

// achtergrond laden 
var home = new Image(); 
home.src = "img/scene2.jpg";
var level1 = new Image(); 
level1.src = "img/welcome.jpg"; 
var level2 = new Image(); 
level2.src = "img/town1.jpg"; 

var msg = new MessageBox();

//msg.text = "Welcome to Storybrooke!"; 
//msg.showMe = true; 

function draw(){ 


    ctx.drawImage(home, 0, 0);

    //msg.draw(); 

}

// de functie 'draw' eenmalig gestart 
draw(); 

//HTML
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="Game_design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Game Mario</title>

</head>

<body>
<center>
    <container> 

    </container>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="700" ></canvas>
</center>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Game_test.js"></script> 
<script src="Object.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I can't put the background as an actual background image, because I would like it to change after a few clicks in the game. 
Can anyone see the problem here? Because I can't ^^"

Comment: When you say that it "doesn't work", does *anything* happen? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: Nope. No errors and I've just tested it with a console.log (in the draw function) and the console.log works fine, but still no image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as posted is missing `})` at the end. Assuming that's a typo, I bet the real problem is that you're not waiting for the images to load. If you change your code a little as in this example:

```
        var home = new Image();
        home.onload = draw;
        home.src = "http://www.placekitten.com/120/220";
```

and also take out that call to `draw()` at the end of the "ready" handler, it should work. [Here is a working CodePen.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/mwfpG)

Comment: haha I forgot to copy the }); from my code yeah, I do have that at the end.  'function draw() { home.onload = function() { ctx.drawImage(home, 0, 0); } } draw(); ' I made it like this, because I will be drawing more images and change the background in the game, and it works okay now :)